# How to run commands from docker-compose.yml to start couchdb

Tags: django, docker, couchdb

I have a webapp written in django which i need to connect with couchdb both are running on docker container. django will store the data in couchdb table named "test". So i need to create "test" table in couch db. But i'm unable to figure out how to achieve this as there is no good material available for reference. I have tried the below codes but it is throwing the following error because couchdb is not up and running. Is there any way to create a table in couchdb using docker-compose.yml or any other alternatives.

I use `docker-compose up` to run the containers

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python ./webapp/server.py
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./webapp/static:/static

    networks:
      - couchserver_network
    depends_on:
      - couchserver

  couchserver:
    image: couchdb
    ports:
       - "5984:5984"
    command: curl -u rob:123456 -X PUT localhost:5984/_users && curl -u rob:123456 -X PUT localhost:5984/test
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=rob
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=123456
    volumes:
        - ./dbdata:/opt/couchdb/data
    networks:
      - couchserver_network


networks:
  couchserver_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Error thrown :

```
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5984: Connection refused
```

If i remove the line "**command: curl -u rob:123456 -X PUT localhost:5984/_users && curl -u rob:123456 -X PUT localhost:5984/test**" below error is thrown :

```
couchserver_1  | {database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,399}]},....
```

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Any sort of help is really appreciated

One more query :
what does the below lines do. I'm novice into docker and this is my first hands on with it

```
 volumes:
     - ./dbdata:/opt/couchdb/data
```

Comment: Looks like the DB is not up when the `curl` commands are executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `command` being used in the compose file overrides the CMD from the Dockerfile that starts the database.

First thing coming in mind is to override the CMD in order to start the DB **AND** execute the curls, but this won't work due to how the DB is being initialized.

A better approach is to have a helper container that executes the curl commands against the DB.

Here is a minimal example that will create the desired databases:

```
version: '3'
services:
  couchserver:
    image: couchdb
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=rob
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=123456
    volumes:
        - ./dbdata:/opt/couchdb/data
  initializer:
    image: curlimages/curl
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - couchserver
    command: ["sh","-c","sleep 15 && curl -u rob:123456 -X PUT couchserver:5984/_users &&  curl -u rob:123456 -X PUT couchserver:5984/test"]
```

Comment: Anderson, initializer works great as standalone with couchdb but when it is added along with django app, the order of execution and running follows couchdb--->djangoapp--->initializer. So still django is unable to connect. I tried building the image twice. in first try initializer created the table but in second try it failed to

Comment: @Bharath, try adding restart_policy on failure on the django service. I'm updating my post to show how to do it. I am adding it in my initializer, you should add it under your django service. The on-failure policy allows you to tell Docker to restart a container if the exit code indicates error but not if the exit code indicates success. This might work only if the django container exits with !=0

Comment: @Anderson, tried it. still no hope..here is the error logs : https://github.com/Bharath369-hub/docker

Comment: @Bharath, there's a 4 minute difference between the first and last logs, right? By that time, the databases should be created already by the initializer, yet the logs are saying "database does not exist". I'm pretty sure this has a different cause. Perhaps there's something wrong in the django container.

Comment: @Anderson if i manually add test table to db...django is working fine. One more issue here is ,in initailizer it is given as couchserver:5984. Which returns unable to locate host. So the table is not getting created

Comment: @Anderson, what if the couchdb has not started within 15 second. will the initailizer fail?
and adding curl image wont make the container size huge? Just for understanding

Comment: docker logs <initializer-container-id> to see if it did its job

Comment: @Anderson, It is working now after i add a network bridge btn couchdb and  django app along with the initializer. Marking this answer as accepted. Btw, in command how can i get the username and password from .env file? { user } would do?